# Printing only one label out of two for the x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

The following tiki code (generated from matlab) prints nicely, but I would like to print only one x label out of two. That is, instead of printing:

10^−14 10^−13 10^−12 10^−11 10^−10 10^−9 10^−8 10^−7 10^−6 10^−5 10^−4

I would like to print:

10^−1 10^−1 10^−10 10^−8 10^−6 10^−4

I searched the pff/tikz manual but did not find anything.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.149in,
height=2.649in,
at={(0.594in,0.521in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
every x tick/.append style={black},
xmode=log,
xmin=1e-14,
xmax=1e-4,
xminorticks=true,minor
xlabel={\large{\Lobj}},
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
every y tick/.append style={black},
ymin=50,
ymax=250,
ylabel={\large{\Cmax}},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
% title={lambda:Cmax}
]
\addplot [color=blue, line width=1.0pt, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
9e-05   59\\
7e-05   59\\
5e-05   59\\
3e-05   64\\
1e-05   99\\
7e-06   107\\
2e-06   138\\
1e-06   141\\
7e-07   159\\
5e-07   165\\
3e-07   166\\
7e-09   168\\
5e-10   185\\
4e-10   193\\
5e-11   202\\
5e-12   228\\
5e-13   237\\
1e-14   240\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xticklabel` to change the definition for the ticklabels of the x axis:

```
xticklabel={%
  \pgfmathMod{\ticknum}{2}%
  \ifdim \pgfmathresult pt >0pt\axisdefaultticklabellog\fi
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=3.149in,
height=2.649in,
at={(0.594in,0.521in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
every x tick/.append style={black},
xmode=log,
xmin=1e-14,
xmax=1e-4,
xminorticks=true,
xlabel={x Text},
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
every y tick/.append style={black},
ymin=50,
ymax=250,
ylabel={y Text},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
label style={font=\large},
xticklabel={%
  \pgfmathMod{\ticknum}{2}%
  \ifdim \pgfmathresult pt >0pt\axisdefaultticklabellog\fi
},
% title={lambda:Cmax}
]
\addplot [color=blue, line width=1.0pt, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
9e-05   59\\
7e-05   59\\
5e-05   59\\
3e-05   64\\
1e-05   99\\
7e-06   107\\
2e-06   138\\
1e-06   141\\
7e-07   159\\
5e-07   165\\
3e-07   166\\
7e-09   168\\
5e-10   185\\
4e-10   193\\
5e-11   202\\
5e-12   228\\
5e-13   237\\
1e-14   240\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks Stephen! I have a followup question, the pff manual has no entry on xticklabel. Where can I find a manual about this? Is it because the code was generated by Matlab that ut has this particular format? Best regards. Alain

Comment: `xticklabel` is described in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) in section "Tick Options", subsection "Tick Coordinates and Label Texts". Maybe you can accept my answer if it solves your problem.